# C# MVC, es posible devolver dos columnas desde SQL?

Tags: c#, mvc

Usualmente en mi API devuelvo valores asi:

```
int Idresult = spExecuter.ExecuteDataRow<int>("dbo.Insertar_Articulo", Parameters);
```

Donde Idresult es el Id del Articulo insertado devuelto en la ejecucion del store procedure "Insertar_Articulo" en base a algunos parametros que le paso.

Es posible recibir dos columnas sin crear una entidad o clase especifica de dos valores?

Ed decir algo como:

```
List<string,string> Idresult = spExecuter.ExecuteDataRow<string,string>("dbo.Notificaciones_INS_REC", Parameters);
```

Usualemente la solucion es crear una clase con dos atributos string y reemplazar el string,string por la clase.

Pero me gustaria saber si existe otro modo, por ejemplo con Tuplas agregando un Key hardcodeado por cada valor u otro metodo?

Comment: Cuando lei tu pregunta lo primero que se me ocurrio fue una tupla. Probaste hacerlo asi?

Comment: Sin exito, opté por crear la clase privada dentro de la clase que utiliza el llamado al Store.

Comment: Pero cuando devolves el procedure y lo tiras a un Var, no lo podes luego devolver como tupla? realizando los pasos adecuados luego

Comment: Me gustaria que en el futuro c# agregara algún tipo de dato especial que acelere ese proceso o pueda reconocer varios campos en una misma linea. Existe el <T>, pero tiene limitaciones.